# How does $ work in NASM, exactly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
message db "Enter a digit ", 0xA,0xD
Length equ $- message
```

Is it used to get the length of a string?
How does it work internally?

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/)?

Comment: I tried but could not understand!

Comment: `$` is usually referred to as the “location counter”. (In other assemblers it can be `*` or `.`)

Comment: Related: what happens if you put `Length equ $- message` in the wrong place might help you understand how it works: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897633/in-nasm-labels-next-to-each-other-in-memory-are-causing-printing-issues

Comment: (`I tried but could not understand!` there's nothing wrong with failing. But it doesn't hurt to document and present what you have tried - even if it should go without saying that you tried *something* before asking for help.)

Comment: also it helps tremendously to explain, which parts of docs you *do* understand, and which not... especially, if you don't understand particular word, etc... Then the answers may explain you things which you don't understand. (explaining whole `$` business from scratch would involve explaining you what is computer, what is CPU, etc... a whole book).

Comment: BTW, did you mean `0xD, 0xA` (CR LF) rather than the other way around?

Answer (score 33):

### This gets the assembler to calculate the string length for you at assemble time

`$` is the address of the current position *before* emitting the bytes (if any) for the line it appears on.   [Section 3.5 of the manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5) doesn't go into much detail.

`$ - msg` is like doing `here - msg`, i.e. **the distance in bytes between the current position (at the end of the string) and the start of the string**.  ([See also this tutorial](https://www.csc.depauw.edu/%7Ebhoward/asmtut/asmtut9.html) on NASM labels and directives like `resb`)

(Related: Most other x86 assemblers also use `$` the same way, except for GAS which uses `.` (period).  [MMIX assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX) uses `@`, which has the right semantic meaning).

---

To understand it better, it may help to see what happens when you get it wrong:  [In NASM labels next to each other in memory are printing both strings instead of first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897633/in-nasm-labels-next-to-each-other-in-memory-are-causing-printing-issues).  This person used

```
HELLO_MSG db 'Hello, World!',0    ; normally you don't want ,0
GOODBYE_MSG db 'Goodbye!',0       ; in explicit-length strings, unless it also needs to be a C-string

hlen equ $ - HELLO_MSG
glen equ $ - GOODBYE_MSG
```

resulting in `hlen` including the length of both strings.

`EQU` evaluates the right hand side right away, to a constant value.  (In some assemblers like FASM, `equ` is a text substitution and you have to use `glen = $ - GOODBYE_MSG` to evaluate with `$` at this position, instead of evaluating `$` in a later `mov ecx, glen` instruction or something.  But NASM's `equ` evaluates on the spot; use `%define` for text substitutions)

---

**Using `$` is exactly equivalent to putting a label at the start of the line and using it instead of `$`.**

The object-size example can also be done using regular labels:

```
msg:   db "Enter a digit "
msgend: 
Length equ msgend - msg
Length2 equ $ - msg     ; Length2 = Length

newline: db 0xA,0xD
Length3 equ $ - msg     ; Length3 includes the \n\r LF CR sequence as well.
                        ; sometimes that *is* what you want
```

You can put `Length equ msgend - msg` anywhere, or `mov ecx, msgend - msg` directly.  (It's sometimes useful to have a label on the end of something, e.g. `cmp rsi, msgend` / `jb .loop` at the bottom of a loop.

BTW, it's usually CR LF, not LF CR.

---

#### Less obvious examples:

```
times 4  dd $
```

assembles the same as this (but without creating a symbol table entry or clashing with an existing name):

```
here:    times 4 dd here
```

In `times 4  dd $`, `$` doesn't update to its own address for each dword, it's still the address of the start of the line.  (Try it in a file by itself and hexdump the flat binary: it's all zeros.)

---

But a `%rep` block is expanded before `$`, so

```
%rep 4
    dd $
%endrep
```

does produce 0, 4, 8, 12 (starting from an output position of `0` in a flat binary for this example.)

```
$ nasm -o foo  rep.asm  && hd foo
00000000  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00
```

---

#### Manually encoding jump displacements:

A normal direct [`call` is `E8 rel32`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/CALL), with the displacement calculated relative to the *end* of the instruction.  (i.e. relative to EIP/RIP while the instruction is executing, because RIP holds the address of the next instruction.  RIP-relative addressing modes work this way, too.)  A dword is 4 bytes, so in a `dd` pseudo-instruction with one operand, the address of the end is `$+4`.  You could of course just put a label on the *next* line and use that.

```
earlyfunc:           ; before the call
    call func        ; let NASM calculate the offset
    db  0xE8
    dd  func - ($ + 4)       ; or do it ourselves
    db  0xE8
    dd  earlyfunc - ($ + 4)  ; and it still works for negative offsets

    ...

func:                ; after the call
```

disassembly output (from `objdump -drwC -Mintel`):

```
0000000000400080 <earlyfunc>:
  400080:       e8 34 00 00 00          call   4000b9 <func>    # encoded by NASM
  400085:       e8 2f 00 00 00          call   4000b9 <func>    # encoded manually
  40008a:       e8 f1 ff ff ff          call   400080 <earlyfunc>  # and backwards works too.
```

If you get the offset wrong, objdump will put the symbolic part as `func+8`, for example.  The relative displacement in the first 2 call instructions differs by 5 because `call rel32` is 5 bytes long and they have the same actual destination, *not* the same relative displacement.  Note that the disassembler takes care of adding the rel32 to the address of the call instructions to show you absolute destination addresses.

You can use `db target - ($+1)` to encode the offset for a short `jmp` or `jcc`.  (But beware: `db 0xEB, target - ($+1)` isn't right, because the end of the instruction is actually `$+2` when you put both the opcode and displacement as multiple args for the same `db` pseudo-instruction.)

---

Related: **`$$` is the start of the current *section***, so `$ - $$` is how far into the current section you are.  But this is only within the current file, so linking two files that put stuff in `.rodata` is different from having two `section .rodata` blocks in the same source file.  See [What's the real meaning of $$ in nasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928741/whats-the-real-meaning-of-in-nasm).

By far the most common use is `times 510-($-$$) db 0` / `dw 0xAA55` to pad (with `db 0`) a boot sector out to 510 bytes, and then add the boot sector signature to make 512 bytes.  ([The NASM manual explains how this works](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo12.html#section-12.1.3))

Comment: Nice examples!  You could perhaps add another one where you manually create a `call rel32` instruction using `db`, `dd`, and `$`.

Comment: @fuz: Thanks for the suggestion.  Finally got around to finishing this edit.

Comment: Fun fact: the MMIX assembler uses `@`  instead of `$` because `@` clearly denotes the place where we are at.

Comment: @PeterCordes can we consider **$** is equal to **RIP**, I was reading some code and I found this `lea rsi, [rel $ +0xffffffffffffffff ]`, which really confused me a lot about what that suppose to mean?

Comment: @zerocool: No, RIP-relative addressing is relative to the start of the *next* instruction, but `$` is the start of *this* instruction.  `[rel $ - 1]` would be the byte before that LEA instruction, addressed with a RIP-relative addressing mode.  (I didn't check the machine code to see if that's how NASM actually assembles it).  `[rip - 1]` would be the last byte of the LEA instruction, the high byte of the rel32.

Comment: so `lea rsi, [rel msg]` is equal to `lea rsi, [rip + msg - nextInsn]` ??? @PeterCordes

Comment: @zerocool: In machine code encoding, yes.  See [How do RIP-relative variable references like "\[RIP + \_a\]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?]([How do RIP-relative variable references like "\[RIP + \_a\]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54745872)) for examples of machine code.  (Note that GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` does literally use `[rip + symbol]` as asm source syntax with the same meaning as `[rel symbol]`, even though that does *not* reflect the machine code encoding.  But `[rip + A - B]` with a difference between symbols should probably work like `[rip + 1

Answer (score 0):

**NASM documentation**

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5

> NASM supports two special tokens in expressions, allowing calculations to involve the current assembly position: the $ and $$ tokens. $ evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line containing the expression; so you can code an infinite loop using JMP $.

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.4

> EQU defines a symbol to a given constant value: when EQU is used, the source line must contain a label. The action of EQU is to define the given label name to the value of its (only) operand. This definition is absolute, and cannot change later. So, for example,
>
> ```
> message         db      'hello, world' 
> msglen          equ     $-message
> ```
>
> defines msglen to be the constant 12