# How do I skip exactly 1 instruction with a jump relative to RIP in x64 asm?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, intel

I'm trying to skip exactly 1 instruction without using labels, an example with labels would be:

```
cmp r12, r13
je dest ; skip the jmp
jmp whatever
dest:
nop
```

However, my limitation is that I can't use labels, so I assume I must create a jump relative to the RIP register. For example (pseudo):

```
cmp r12, r13
je rip+0x05 ; this would obviously depend on the length of the next instruction
jmp whatever
nop
```

However, I lack knowledge to produce anything working, also as far as I know, it's not possible to read/write the RIP register without hacks.

**EDIT:** I'm only familiar with Intel syntax and I use Keystone as assembler. I will take the bytes from the assembly and load it into an executable memory location. I'm using my own website to get the bytes from the assembly, you might get the idea if you look at [it](https://ioncodes.github.io/sam/).

**EDIT 2:** I tried Jesters and Margaret Blooms comments, which suggest to use:

```
je .+0x05
; or
je $+0x05
```

However, I can confirm that both don't work with Keystone! Luckily, I noticed that Keystone is able to process this code:

```
je +0x05
```

Is anyone able to confirm that this works?

**EDIT 3:** I tried it out with NASM and the $ prefix works fine with my tested code. I used this to test it:

```
section .text       
global _WinMain@16       

_WinMain@16:
    jmp $+2+2 ; skip this jmp and the next jmp (each 2 bytes)
    jmp $
    ret 16
```

It works as expected. Also [defuse](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly) produces the same output as Keystone. The only difference is that defuse uses the $ prefix and Keystone doesn't need one at all!
Keystone equivalent is:

```
jmp +4
jmp .
ret 16
```

Comment: `je .+5` or whatever syntax your assembler (which you didn't specify) supports for the current address. Also, what's wrong with labels?

Comment: If you know the length of the next instruction this can be done the way Jester says. However if you don't know the length of the next instruction you'll have no chance!

Comment: @Jester, the assembler won't assemble that.

Comment: @MartinRosenau, I'm preprocessing assembly of a different architecture. So I definitely can get the length after initial processing.

Comment: Branches are relative, you don't need the RIP-relative addressing mode. But you must know the instruction length unless you can afford to make a [nop sled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_slide) of length 15 and always jump 2 + 15 = 17 bytes ahead.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, I already thought about nop sledding it, but it might be better if I just implement it properly. The structure of the project allows me to get the length after initial processing, so I will definitely do it.

Comment: I just noticed something thanks to @Jester! I updated my question.

Comment: Note that Jester also included a dot before the plus. Some assemblers use a dollar ($) instead.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, I just edited my question with the result.

Comment: Examine the generated machine code, you should be able to verify whether it works.

Comment: @Jester, As far as I know, 0x74 is JE and other byte seems correct. I just quickly tried it with NASM and it works! Can you create an answer, so this can be marked as answered!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in NASM and MASM `$` isn't a prefix.  [It's a stand-alone keyword / symbol which refers to the address of the current line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly).

`je $+5` won't work: `jmp rel32` is 5 bytes, and the short JCC is 2.  So you need `je $+7` to skip a 5-byte instruction, or `$+4` to skip a 2-byte instruction.

The rel8 displacement will be `0x05` or `0x02`, because jumps encode their displacement from the end of the instruction.  But NASM's `$` label gives the address of the start of the instruction, and the assembler always calculates the relative displacement for you, based on the target address.  So with `$+x`, you need to include the length of the current instruction.

If you want to encode the rel8 yourself, you could use `db` pseudo-instructions to emit the bytes you want.  e.g. `db 0xEB, 0x02`

---

**Your entire approach / goal of not using any labels is fundamentally flawed unless you have a *reliable* way to know how long the next instruction is**.  (e.g. by using `jmp NEAR` or `jmp SHORT` to force a long or short encoding).  All you can do is encode a jump that goes forward a fixed number of bytes, not one that skips one instruction, regardless of width.

But seriously just use a label; x86 jumps are always relative anyway, so let your assembler make life easier for you and calculate the correct relative displacement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do know that $ is a symbol, but I couldn‘t find a better name at that time. I have a reliable way to calculate the length of the next instruction.