# Why do write syscalls print `%` at end on linux x86_64 (nasm)?

Tags: linux, nasm, x86-64, zsh, system-calls

The following hello-world program displays a `%` sign at the end of the printed string. Why is this and how can I remove it?

Here is my program:

```
section .data
    msg db  "hello, world!"

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 1      ; syscall 1 (write)
    mov rdi, 1      ; arg 1 = 1 (stdout)
    mov rsi, msg    ; arg 2 = msg ("hello, world!")
    mov rdx, 13     ; arg 3 = 13 (char count)
    syscall         ; call write
    mov rax, 60     ; syscall 60 (exit)
    mov rdi, 0      ; arg 1 = 0 (OK)
    syscall         ; call exit
```

And here is the output when I run the executable: `hello, world!%`

Thanks in advance.

Edit: It seems to be caused by zsh (not reproducible in bash). The question is why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: Turns out it was my shell. It happens on zsh and not bash.

Comment: But why would this happen on zsh? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Isn't this just the prompt symbol? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Explanations/Shell_Prompt#Appearance_of_the_prompt

Comment: Did some more testing and turns out zsh is inserting `%` followed by a newline when the printed string doesn't end with a newline, whereas bash doesn't do this.

Comment: See [Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/167582)  (**TL;DR** - it's a zsh *feature*, that can be disabled using `unsetopt prompt_cr prompt_sp`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because your program's output doesn't end with a newline.

---

Your program isn't printing the `%`.  You can verify this by piping its output into `hexdump -C` or similar.

You can also use `strace` to trace what system calls its making, but that doesn't show the *output*, so it doesn't rule out the kernel magically adding a `%`.  (But you can be sure the kernel doesn't do that.  The only munging that's possible is for `write` to return early, without having written the full buffer.  This is only likely with large buffer sizes, especially when writing to a pipe with a buffer larger than the pipe-buffer (maybe 64kiB).

---

This is a ZSH feature for partial lines: 
[Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol).  You didn't say it was a highlighted % symbol.  Accurate / complete descriptions are important.

(An earlier version of this answer assumed you were using `%` as your prompt in ZSH.  `%` is sometimes used as a prompt, but more often in C-shells like tcsh, not Bourne-derived shells like bash and zsh.)

You'd get exactly the same thing from `echo -n "hello, world!"`.  e.g. in bash:

```
peter@volta:/tmp$ echo -n 'hello world!'
hello world!peter@volta:/tmp$
```

In ZSH:

```
volta:/tmp$ echo -n 'hello world!' 
hello world!%
volta:/tmp$      # and the % on the previous line is in inverse-video
```

Bash just prints `$PS1` (or runs `$PROMPT_COMMAND`) after a foreground command exits, regardless of cursor position.  It can't directly check that your program's output ended with a newline.  I guess ZSH uses VT100 escape codes to query the cursor position to detect cases where programs leave the cursor not at the start of a line.

You also get this when you `cat` a file that doesn't end with a newline, or any number of other cases.

---

**To fix it, include a newline (ASCII linefeed, 0xa) in your message**:

```
section .rodata
    msg: db  "hello, world!", 0xa
    msglen equ $ - msg               ; use mov edx, msglen
    msgend:                          ; or  mov edx, msgend - msg
```

See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) for more details on getting the assembler to compute the size for you.

Don't omit the `:` on data labels in NASM; it's good style and avoids name conflicts with instruction mnemonics and assembler directives.

NASM (but not YASM) accepts C-style esacapes inside backquotes, so instead of the numeric ASCII code for a newline, you could write

```
  msg: db  `hello, world!\n`
```

Comment: I wish I could give an extra vote for also pointing out how to compute the message length instead of the fragile counting...

Comment: Thanks! As for the message length, I'm just getting started on a tutorial so I haven't gotten that far yet, but good to know.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly for more details, so you can go upvote that for the length-calculation part :)  I also updated with info on ZSH doing this on purpose; good find with that comment on the question.