# ptrace x86 function trampoline

Tags: x86, hook

I'm currently working on a project and it involves replacing a function by another. Let's say I have this simple function I want to hook:

```
int bad_func(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

I want to replace it with the following method:

```
int good_func(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

At the moment here is how I proceed:

1. Attach to the process with `ptrace`
2. Get the address of `bad_func` in the code segment
3. Inject `mmap2` syscall to allocate a new `rwx` memory segment
4. Copy the assembly code of `good_func` to the newly allocated segment
5. Replace the first bytes of `bad_func` with a `JMP good_func` instruction

All of this is working great, I can confirm that the child process goes into the newly allocated memory and execute `good_func`. The problem is that it never returns to the rest of the code that hasn't been executed yet.

Since both methods contains the following instructions,

```
push %ebp
mov  %esp, %ebp
...
pop  %ebp
ret
```

I suppose that I don't need to save/change the `ebp` and `esp` registers for it to work, but I guess I'm wrong...

Does anyone know how I can achieve my goal?

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I suppose you've forgotten to store `good_fun` function return address in stack. You can try to replace your `JMP good_func` to `call good_func` off cause it should looks like `leal $good_function_address,%eax;  call *%eax` Check [this](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2012/fall/cs301/lecture/09_24_call_and_ret.html)

Comment: I replaced the `jmp` instruction by `call` but it still has the same behaviour... Furthermore, even if it had worked, I don't think the `call` instruction is the way to go. Indeed, it would execute the `good_func` function and then come back to `bad_func` and execute its code. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: When you patch bad_func, I presume you are patching it with a relative jump.  The address that the jump is relative to is the one following the jump opcode, so the patch should be 0xea, 0xcd, good_func_addr - ((long)bad_func+6).  It is easy to get this wrong, and have the program ‘appear to almost work’ because it lands on a nearby opcode that messes up the stack.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the opcode of the relative `jmp` x86 instruction is `0xE9` and not `0xEA 0xCD` thus the instruction length is 5. Nonetheless, I tried your solution and it didn't work.. I don't even reach `good_func` anymore

Comment: @mevets: faku is right, you want a [5-byte `jmp rel32`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html).  Replacing the first 5 bytes of `bad_func` should do the trick, turning it into a tail-call of `good_func`.  (like the compiler would create if you compiled `int bad_func(a,b) { return good_func(a,b); }` with optimization enabled.

Comment: If you replace the very first bytes of the instruction (and not just the bytes after the prologue like GDB takes you to when you set a breakpoint), the previous contents of `bad_func` don't matter *at all*: they don't execute.  You should single-step your code with `gdb`.  Use `si` to single-step instructions.  See the bottom of [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for gdb asm tips.

Comment: See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744) for an example of manually encoding branch displacements with NASM (`jmp` will be the same as `call`, just a different opcode.)

Comment: @PeterCordes As I said before, I already replaced the very first bytes of `bad_func` with a `call good_func` instruction but no success... About single-stepping my code with gdb, can I do that even if I'm in a tracer process and don't have access to the tracee? At the moment, I implemented a simple debug function that prints the state of the `ebp` register for each instruction once I hit the newly allocated segment I mentioned in my question. Since it's pretty late here, I didn't have the courage to debug deeply but it seems like there is a problem with the stack.

Comment: It needs to be a `jmp`, not a `call`.  Victor was wrong.  Otherwise you're pushing a new bogus return address that will take you back into the middle of the function you've overwritten, instead of tail-calling.  re: debugging: have you tried triggering a core dump?  IDK if you can get it to include the modified text segment, though.  But that would let you check with external tools (like a disassembler or GDB) what the jump target address is.