# Call absolute address in x64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, function-pointers

I could not figure this out, I can make an instruction like this and it works no problem

```
call ffffdd80d60e4000
```

But how would I go about converting this into bytes? I looked at the instruction in memory and shows weird stuff like

```
0xe8 0x00 0x40 0x0e 0xd6
```

The only thing I can identify is the e8 which is the call opcode. Can someone explain what the other 4 bytes are and how would I go about converting an instruction like this into a byte array if the address I need to call is a DWORD64 value? I tried and I can't simply copy the bytes of the address and add an 0xe8 at the start.
Sorry if it might be a dumb question, but I searched through books and websites and couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: It's a relative address. You need to know the address of the current (actually the following) instruction and calculate the difference to the target. See also section _7.3.8.1 Unconditional Transfer Instructions_ in the basic architecture manual.

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks. It's weird cause I was looking at the x64 asm documentation and it said that an e8 is a call to a absolute address. Guess I can just calculate it then.

Comment: You looked wrong. The manual says: _E8 cd CALL rel32 Call near, relative, displacement relative to next instruction._

Comment: related: encoding a `call` instruction manually with `target - ($ + 5)` in NASM: [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jester said, normally a call uses a relative address. If you want to use an absolute address, you can put the destination in a register like this:

```
    48 b8 00 40 0e d6  mov rax, 0xffffdd80d60e4000
    80 dd ff ff
    ff d0              call rax
```

You can also call an address that is in memory. For example if the destination address is in memory at [rsp+8], then

```
    ff 54 24 08        call [rsp+8]
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about putting it in a register before, but it's not really gonna work for my purpose, since this instruction is gonna be called every second or less  and the registers value would be overwritten.