# macro vs equ in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, nasm

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the two, the following example really had me puzzled:

```
section .data
msg: db "Thank you"
var: dd 0x31323334
len equ msg-4

section .text
global main
main:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, var-len
```

```
section .data
%define len msg-4
msg: db "Thank you"
var: dd 0x31323334


section .text
global main
main:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, var-len
```

The first program prints "Thank you4321", which is quite obvious, but for some reason the second program prints "Thank"
I've tried tracking the values and I got : `var = 0x2011, msg = 0x2008, len = 0x2004`, but somehow `edx` got `0x05` where I would think it'd be `0x2011-0x2004 = 0x0D`
Any idea why this is?
Another thing I noticed with equ is that if I calculate `len-var` I get 0 , my guess is that it has no address in memory because it's a macro? Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have fixed your code. You should always copy and paste your code into Stackoverflow. You spelled `define` wrong and you left out `dd` when defining `var`.

Comment: Thanks and sorry about that.

Comment: Just for the record, `len equ msg-4` has a totally misleading name.  Don't call it `len`, it's the address of 4 bytes before `msg`.  See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744) - normally you'd `len equ var - msg`, or (right after msg, before var) `len equ $-msg`.  I assume you were playing around starting with something like that and didn't change the name after modifying it to be totally different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first code works because when you use `EQU`, this line:

```
len equ msg-4
```

sets `len` to the value computed from the expression `msg-4` and the result is stored in the constant `len`. Then when you do:

```
mov edx, var-len
```

The precomputed value of `len` is subtracted from the offset of `var` which will be 13 which is what you'd expect.

When you use:

```
%define len msg-4
```

it defines `len` to be the *string* `msg-4`. When you use `len` like this:

```
mov edx, var-len
```

Text substitution turns it into this:

```
mov edx, var-msg-4
```

Which will yield the value 5. This is not the calculation you wanted. What you want it to produce is:

```
mov edx, var-(msg-4)
```

To do that change the `%define` statement to be:

```
%define len (msg-4)
```

When text substitution is done it will yield the expression:

```
mov edx, var-(msg-4)
```

When computed it should produce the value 13 and put it in *EDX*.