# What is an alternative way to see length of a string in ASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I noticed at my ASM book that author uses that `LENGTHOF str` for finding the size of byte it is searching. Code:

```
.data
alpha BYTE "ABCDEFGH",0
.code
mov edi,OFFSET alpha            ; EDI points to the string
mov al,'F'                      ; search for the letter F
mov ecx,LENGTHOF alpha          ; set the search count
cld                             ; direction = forward
repne scasb                     ; repeat while not equal
jnz quit                        ; quit if letter not found
dec edi                         ; found: back up EDI
```

Is there a way to replace the `LENGTHOF alpha` part? I am aware that `len equ $-alpha` exists but for the sake of learning i search for more under the hood and "primitive" practices. So that I can understand better how that really works.

Comment: The `repne scasb` should not try to find content **where the zero-terminator sits**. Therefore `mov ecx, LENGTHOF alpha - 1` is already better!

Answer (score 2):

You are right, `LENGTHOF alpha` could be replaced with `len equ $-alpha` declared at the very tail of `alpha` definition:

```
.data
alpha BYTE "ABCDEFGH",0
len equ $-alpha
.code
 mov ecx,len
```

Operators `LENGTHOF` and `OFFSET` can be treated as names of functions which return the number of bytes, in your example `9` and `0`. They are calculated at **assembly time** and their names depend on the assembler. In MASM they are called [operator LENGTHOF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-lengthof?view=msvc-160) and [operator OFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-offset?view=msvc-160), in other assemblers the name may differ, for instance see [attributes in €ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/index.htm#Attributes).

Comment: They're not "functions" in the asm sense of something you can `call`.  A better term might be "operators".  Related: [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744) for details of what `$-alpha` is really doing.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not an assemble-time constant string, then you'd either

- know it's length already (because of how it was input) so you could still use `rep scasb` as a slow-ish `memchr`, with that runtime variable length as ECX.
- or if it's an "implicit length" C-style string and you just have a pointer, you could search for the terminating `0` or `'F'` (i.e. implement `strchr`) using a loop that checks for both things.

Or the even slower way would be to search for the `0` first to find the length (i.e. implement strlen), then use that as ECX for your `rep scasb` (`memchr`).

Obviously all these search loops can be done with simple instructions in a manual loop like `mov` and `cmp`/`jne`; `rep scasb` isn't magic.

`strchr` and `strlen` and so on are names of standard C functions.  I'm using them as shorthand to describe the search loop you'd want to use.