# Understanding some Assembly "Hello World" code: equ $ - msg1 prints both messages?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have the following Assembly code:

```
section .text
      global _start
_start:
       mov edx,len2
       mov ecx,msg1
       mov ebx,1
       mov eax,4
       int 0x80     ; write(1, msg1, len2)
       mov eax,1  ;system call number (sys_exit) 
       int 0x80   ;call kernel

section  .data

   msg1 db   'Hello '
   len1 equ  $ - msg1
   msg2 db   'world!',0xa
   len2 equ  $ - msg1
```

I have been told that this code should print "Hello World!" but I can't understand why?

When I first looked at it I was sure it supposed to print just "Hello ".
Can someone please help me to understand this, please?

Comment: `len2` is defined as `$ - msg1` not as `$ - msg2` so it includes the length of the `Hello ` as well.

Comment: @Jester thank you!

Comment: Do not post pictures of code please!  Instead, always post code as text.  I have downvoted your question and will retract the downvote once you [edit] your question and change your picture into text.

Comment: @fuz I have edit the question and added the code as text.

Comment: @none Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

as @Jester said in the comment the reason is that `len2` is defined as `$ - msg1` not as `$ - msg2` so it includes the length of the Hello as well.

Comment: Related: [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744).  The code in your question looks like an intentional trick / obfuscation: defining len2 as the total length, but calling it len2 is super weird.  So the actual length of the 2nd part is `len2 - len1`, which you'd need if you ever wanted to print just the "world!" part.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, this is a question from a previous exam about Assembly that I'm learning to.

Comment: Ok, but if I ever saw code like that in real life, I'd fix it by renaming `len2` to `len_total`.  As written, it's intentionally misleading naming, to the point where I'd consider it a bug.  IDK if that makes a good exam question or not.  Using `len2` with `msg1` in the code does encourage you to look closely at how they're defined, instead of assuming that they're defined the way you'd expect (as the length of the corresponding message number).