# Linux kernel rootkit: read data from memory and use the retrieved data as an offset

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

In the development of my BSc thesis (a rootkit for the 5.4 Linux Kernel), I found myself having to identify a function address (i.e., the address of `do_syscall_64()`) in memory. I don't know it in advance 'cause there is KASLR.
What I'm doing is:

- retrieve the system call handler via MSRs;
- scan the memory location starting from the base address of `entry_SYSCALL_64`, which is the system call handler's code block, until I find the actual call to `do_syscall_64()`;
- isolate 4 bytes after the opcode (i.e., `e8`), that is the offset to which the execution flow will jump after the call:

```
e8 c4 bd f8 ff  call   0xffffffff81b8be40 <do_syscall_64>
```

So, what should I do with the hex offset retrieved? 
I found out that the address specified after this `call` instruction is an offset from the base code segment.
Do I need to convert the offset into decimal and add it to the base code segment address?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a question about understanding machine code. The linux kernel is irrelevant to the question, is that right?

Comment: For analysing assembler instrucions it would greatly help to know the CPU architecture.

Comment: @user253751 yes, you're right

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to get the absolute address from this? https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call <- E8 + 32 bit x -> x is sign extended to 64-bits and added to the address where the instruction is.

Comment: The signed 32-bit offset needs to be sign-extended to 64 bits and added to the address after the current instruction, so the called function will be at the address of the e8 opcode plus 5 plus the sign-extended offset.

Comment: Yup, the 4-byte rel32 offset is a native (little) endian `int32_t` relative to the *end* of the 5-byte `call rel32` instruction, like in [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744) (manually encoding a `call rel32` with NASM).  So yeah, like @IanAbbott said, `call_addr + 5 + rel32`, where call_addr is a `char*` or `uintptr_t`.  If you compile your code with standard kernel options (including `-fno-strict-aliasing`), you can just load it like `int32_t rel32  = *(int32_t*)( e8_call_addr + 1 );`.