# Is it possible for a program to read itself?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

**Theoretical question**. But let's say I have written an assembly program. I have "labelx:" I want the program to read at this memory address and only this size and print to stdout.

Would it be something like

```
jmp labelx
```

And then would i then use the Write syscall , making sure to read from the next instruction from labelx:

```
mov rsi,rip
mov rdi,0x01
mov rdx,?
mov rax,0x01
syscall
```

to then output to stdout.

However how would I obtain the size to read itself? Especially if there is a
label after the code i want to read or code after. Would I have to manually
count the lines?

```
mov rdx,rip+(bytes*lines)
```

And then syscall with populated registers for the syscall to write to from rsi to rdi. Being stdout.

Is this Even possible? Would i have to use the read syscall first, as the write system call requires rsi to be allocated memory buffer. However I assumed .text is already allocated memory and is read only. Would I have to allocate onto the stack or heap or a static buffer first before write, if it's even possible in the first place?

I'm using NASM syntax btw. And pretty new to assembly. And just a question.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the size"? And what do you want to print? The binary machine code or the corresponding assembler instructions?

Comment: The `.text` section is just bytes in memory, no different from `section .rodata` where you might normally put `msg: db "hello", 10`.  You can get the assembler to calculate the size by putting label at the start/end, and using `mov edx, prog_end - prog_start` inside the code at the point where you want that size in RDX.  See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494744) for more about subtracting two labels to get a size.

Comment: @chtz The bytes of the instructions themselves. And essentially a small section of code, which has x amount of lines, kinda like a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `.text` section is just bytes in memory, no different from section `.rodata` where you might normally put `msg: db "hello", 10`.  x86 is a Von Neumann architecture (not Harvard), so there's no distinction between code pointers and data pointers, other than what you choose to do with them.  Use `objdump -drwC -Mintel` on a linked executable to see the machine-code bytes, or GDB's `x` command in a running process, to see bytes anywhere.

You can get the assembler to calculate the size by putting labels at the start/end of the part you want, and using `mov edx, prog_end - prog_start` in the code at the point where you want that size in RDX.

See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) for more about subtracting two labels (in the same section) to get a size. (Where `$` is an implicit label at the start of the current line, although `$` isn't likely what you want here.)

To get the current address into a register, you need a RIP-relative LEA, not `mov`, because RIP isn't a general-purpose register and there's no special form of `mov` that reads it.

```
here:
    lea rsi, [rel here]     ; with DEFAULT REL you could just use [here]
    mov edi, 1              ; stdout fileno
    mov edx, .end - here    ; assemble-time constant size calculation
    mov eax, 1              ; __NR_write
    syscall
.end:
```

This is fully position-independent, unlike if you used `mov esi, here`.  ([How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register))

The LEA *could* use `lea rsi, [rel $]` to assemble to the same machine-code bytes, but you want a label there so you can  subtract them.

I optimized your MOV instructions to use 32-bit operand-size, implicitly zero-extending into the full 64-bit RDX and RAX.  (And RDI, but `write(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)` only looks at EDI anyway for the file descriptor).

**Note that you can `write` any bytes of any section; there's nothing special about having a block of code write itself.**  In the above example, put the start/end labels anywhere.  (e.g. `foo:` and `.end:`, and `mov edx, foo.end - foo` taking advantage of how NASM local labels work, by appending to the previous non-local label, so you can reference them from somewhere else.  Or just give them both non-dot names.)

Comment: For label arithmetic like your `.end - here` example I like to use a NASM-style local label that's just a dot to indicate the start of a structure. For example, [here's a `.:` label](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/c2d96de77120/source/msg.asm#l1484) and a few lines below [there's the user of it](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/c2d96de77120/source/msg.asm#l1497).

Comment: @ecm: Not sure if I like `.` specifically (e.g. GAS uses `.` the way NASM uses `$` so it could be confusing to some readers).  But yeah probably good to use a generically-named local label at the start, so its `.end - .start` instead of `.end - nonlocal` that will break if you transplant it to somewhere else or change the nonlocal name.